# Need to perform some custom actions when a site collection gets created using remote event receiver in sharepoint 2013 apps

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

There is no any "SiteCreated" or "SiteCreating" type of event receiver in app model. But, I want to trigger some events on the site collection creation. There are some web level events in the app model but I need some sort of functionality which will execute when any site collection gets created.

Will this be possible through remote event receiver on "WebProvisioned" event??

Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

Lalit, you can not deploy custom actions on site collection creatiion event in App model because app it just a web which is created when app is deployed on your web or site collection.
So, if you want to deploy your custom actions, do it in App Installation event. 
Open properties of your app project and set "true" to "Handle App Installed" event.

Answer (score 0):

Rishi is correct. Those type of events are not supported by apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Remote Event Receiver using Apps model (hosted-provider), but I do not know you have a method to capture the event of a site crearcion...